# Отступы программирования и пустое пространство

Tags: любой-язык, multilanguage

Я пытаюсь понять пробелы и отступы, которые используются при написании программы. Изменяет ли количество пробелов или отступов значение программы или произвольно?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Смотря в каком языке программирования. В большинстве языков вроде C/C++ или Java использование пробелов или табов -- это просто хорошая практика программирования, т.к. значительно улучшается читаемость кода. Просто сравните, как лучше:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int n;
    std::cin >> n;

    float result = 1;
    for(int i = 1; i <= n; ++i)
    {
        result *= (2*float(i) - 1)/float(i);
    }

    std::cout << result << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Без отступов:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
int n;
std::cin >> n;

float result = 1;
for(int i = 1; i <= n; ++i)
{
result *= (2*float(i) - 1)/float(i);
}
std::cout << result << std::endl;
return 0;
}
```

Однако для Python использование пробелов обязательно, т.к. с их помощью выделяются блоки кода:

```
lst = [5,150,60,150,154,3,49]
for index, i in enumerate(lst):
    if i > 100:
        print(index)
```

Так будет неправильно

```
lst = [5,150,60,150,154,3,49]
for index, i in enumerate(lst):
if i > 100:
print(index)
```

По сути пробельные отступы играют ту же роль, что фигурные скобки или операторы `begin`, `end` в Pascal.

Отдельно ещё можно вспомнить такой язык, как [Whitespace](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace), в котором в принципе используются только табы, пробелы или символы перевода строки в качестве управляющих конструкций. Однако я думаю, что в серьезной практике Вы его вряд ли будете использовать.

Answer (score 3):

В подавляющем большинстве языков отступы и пробелы ни на что не влияют и используются для удобства форматирования и чтения кода. Можно хоть в одну строчку писать, ни на что не повлияет.

В языке Python отступы важны и формируют блоки кода (примерно как фигурные скобки {} в других популярных языках). Похожая ситуация была в старых версиях языков Fortran и COBOL.

Comment: Значит, значение языка происходит только от фактических символов и жетонов?

Comment: @CodyRutscher пожалуйста, не надо называть токены жетонами, у слова token есть и другие значения